# Count max interval of cells with numbers before blank cell in Excel

Tags: excel, count, int, row

is there a way to count, just using formulas, intervals of cells with numbers in a row (before a blank cell appears) and display the value of the "biggest chain" found? I am doing a research about automatization in Twitter. I have a list of n Users. There is one column for each hour of the research, and in every cell there is the number of tweets published for each user during this hour. If a user didn't publish in one specific hour, this cell is empty (here X means an empty cell):

User 1: X X X 1 1 1 2 1 3 8 4 2 1 3 1 1 1 1 X 2 X

User 2: 1 2 X 2 3 1 3 X X 2 1 8 7 2 1 2 3 X 1 3 X

I could conclude that User 1 uses some kind of automatization because he was active for 15 hours in a row.

User 2, although so active as user 1, was active just for 8 hours in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your first row of data showing user in A2 and tweet numbers in `B2:V2` you can use this "array formula" in X2

`=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(B2:V2<>"",COLUMN(B2:V2)),IF(B2:V2="",COLUMN(B2:V2))))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and copy down

That gives me 15 and 8 for your sample data